# Deactivated WordPress plugins, now cannot access site

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue with the RSS feed not working, so I deactivated all WordPress plugins to see if that helps fix the issue. Now, unfortunately, after deactivating all plugins, I cannot access the site at all. It just loads a blank page. Can someone please help me?

Comment: try setting `WP_DEBUG` to true in your `wp-config.php` file and see if you get any error messages which can help you track down the problem.

Comment: _"It just loads a blank page"_ best thing is to check your error log, these must be something useful there

Comment: I got this: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_ie() in /var/www/vhosts/familydollar/wp-content/themes/foodpress2/admin/theme-functions.php on line 86

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I activate Wordpress plugins without the dashboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877668/how-do-i-activate-wordpress-plugins-without-the-dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your theme using ftp. Your theme is using a function from a plugin, and since that plugin is deleted, the function no longer exists, triggering the fatal error. If you delete your theme via ftp, wordpress will automatically load a default theme. You can just then login , upload your plugins first and then upload your theme again via wordpress